# Updating an activity using the API

Tags: api, activities

I'm looking at the API and the options to update an Activity are struck through.

Is there a way of updating an activity with the API? COUld someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Activity Create API with an id in the parameter list. That should function as an update.